# Reduce SQL query result with getting sum for an object

Tags: javascript, mysql, reduce

I need to resolve 2 major problems.

> 1. Need to remove duplicate rows which I getting as a result of the SQL join query (which has one to many relationship).
> 2. Need to reduce the SQL result calculating the sum of the corresponding values.

My SQL query is as follows.

```
SELECT
    ki.item_code,
    i.NAME AS item_name,
    it.item_type_name,
    ist.item_sub_type_name,
    s.company_name,
    rg.delivered_quantity,
    rg.measuring_unit AS delivered_measuring_unit,
    DATE_FORMAT( rg.manufactured_date, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS manufactured_date,
    DATE_FORMAT( rg.expiry_date, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS expiry_date,
    ki.total_quantity,
    ki.measuring_unit AS total_measuring_unit,
    ki.available_quantity 
FROM
    vx_hms.kitchen_inventory ki
    INNER JOIN vx_hms.issued_items ii ON ki.issued_items_id = ii.id
    INNER JOIN vx_hms.main_inventory mi ON ii.main_inventory_id = mi.id
    INNER JOIN vx_hms.good_received_note grn ON mi.good_received_note_no = grn.good_received_note_no
    INNER JOIN vx_hms.received_goods rg ON grn.good_received_note_no = rg.good_received_note_no
    INNER JOIN vx_hms.items i ON i.item_code = ki.item_code
    INNER JOIN vx_hms.item_type it ON i.item_type = it.item_type_name
    INNER JOIN vx_hms.item_sub_type ist ON i.item_sub_type = ist.item_sub_type_name
    INNER JOIN vx_hms.supplier s ON grn.supplier_id = s.id
    INNER JOIN vx_hms.supplier_items si ON s.id = si.supplier_id 
WHERE
    si.active_status = 1 
    AND rg.active_status = 1 
    AND s.active_status = 1 
ORDER BY
    rg.expiry_date
```

This is the SQL result I get.

```
    [ {
    item_code: '130A',
    item_name: 'Item_name',
    item_type_name: 'Food',
    item_sub_type_name: 'Rice',
    company_name: 'Abc pvt ltd',
    delivered_quantity: 100,
    delivered_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    manufactured_date: null,
    expiry_date: null,
    total_quantity: 10,
    total_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    available_quantity: 10 },
   {
    item_code: '130A',
    item_name: 'Item_name',
    item_type_name: 'Food',
    item_sub_type_name: 'Rice',
    company_name: 'Abc pvt ltd',
    delivered_quantity: 100,
    delivered_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    manufactured_date: null,
    expiry_date: null,
    total_quantity: 5,
    total_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    available_quantity: 5 },
   {
    item_code: '130A',
    item_name: 'Item_name',
    item_type_name: 'Food',
    item_sub_type_name: 'Rice',
    company_name: 'Abc pvt ltd',
    delivered_quantity: 100,
    delivered_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    manufactured_date: null,
    expiry_date: null,
    total_quantity: 5,
    total_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    available_quantity: 5 },
   {
    item_code: '130A',
    item_name: 'Item_name',
    item_type_name: 'Food',
    item_sub_type_name: 'Rice',
    company_name: 'Abc pvt ltd',
    delivered_quantity: 100,
    delivered_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    manufactured_date: null,
    expiry_date: null,
    total_quantity: 10,
    total_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    available_quantity: 10 } ]
```

It has duplicate rows. I tried using GROUP BY and DISTINCT, but It didn't work for me.

And I tried to reduce the result as follows. I think It is not suitable to use 'includes()' as it ignores similar values in the SQL result.

```
    const inventoryByItemCode = _.reduce(result, function(a, item) {

const { item_code, item_name, item_type_name, item_sub_type_name, company_name, delivered_quantity, delivered_measuring_unit, manufactured_date, expiry_date, total_quantity, total_measuring_unit, available_quantity } = item;

if  (!a[item_code]) {
   a[item_code] = { item_code, item_name, item_type_name, 
   item_sub_type_name, delivered_measuring_unit, company_name:[], 
   delivered_quantity:[], manufactured_date:[], expiry_date:[], 
   total_quantity:[], total_measuring_unit, available_quantity:[] };
}
if  (!a[item_code].company_name.includes(company_name)) {
   a[item_code].company_name.push(company_name);
}
if  (!a[item_code].delivered_quantity.includes(delivered_quantity)) {                
   a[item_code].delivered_quantity.push(delivered_quantity);
}               
if  (!a[item_code].total_quantity.includes(total_quantity)) {
   a[item_code].total_quantity.push(total_quantity);
}
if  (!a[item_code].manufactured_date.includes(manufactured_date)) {
   a[item_code].manufactured_date.push(manufactured_date);
}
if  (!a[item_code].expiry_date.includes(expiry_date)) {
   a[item_code].expiry_date.push(expiry_date);
}
if  (!a[item_code].available_quantity.includes(available_quantity)) {                   
   a[item_code].available_quantity.push(available_quantity);
}
return a;
}, {});

const obj = Object.values(inventoryByItemCode);
```

In my case, I need to calculate the total of 'total_quantity' as follows.

```
[ { item_code: '130A',
    item_name: 'Item_name',
    item_type_name: 'Food',
    item_sub_type_name: 'Rice',
    delivered_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    company_name: [ 'Abc pvt ltd' ],
    delivered_quantity: [ 100 ],
    manufactured_date: [ null ],
    expiry_date: [ null ],
    total_quantity: 15,
    total_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    available_quantity: [5, 10] } ]
```

Comment: MySQL is not the same as SQL Server (MSSQL), can you fix the mistagging..

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: But as a suggestion you can use MySQL's native [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html) generating functions.. To aggregate the arrays per group use [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)  atleast of your MySQL version supports it.

Comment: do u want put in a array each available_quantity when is repeat by item_code?

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo No. actually, It should be followed by the company_name (available _quantity should display according to its company name). here two values belong to the same company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't sure if this will work for each use case. i thinking your db query or db standardization can be better.

```js
const products = [
  {
    company_name: "Abc pvt ltd",
    total_quantity: 10,
    available_quantity: 10
  },
  {
    company_name: "Abc pvt ltd",
    total_quantity: 5,
    available_quantity: 5
  },
  {
    company_name: "Abc pvt ltd",
    total_quantity: 5,
    available_quantity: 5
  },
  {
    company_name: "Abc pvt ltd",
    total_quantity: 10,
    available_quantity: 10
  }
];

const result = products.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (!acc.company_name) {
    acc = {
      company_name: obj.company_name,
      total_quantity: 0,
      available_quantity: []
    };
  }
  if (acc.available_quantity.findIndex(i => i === obj.available_quantity) === -1) {
    acc.total_quantity += obj.total_quantity;
    acc.available_quantity.push(obj.available_quantity);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log("result filtered: ", result);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Christian Carrillo. It works with my scenario.

Comment: How can I improve the reduce function when I have different item_codes. Your answer works very well for one item_code.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following code, it filters duplicates and it will group up by `item_code` and `company_name`.

I've left some comments in the script so you can understand what i did there.

```js
let a = [{
    item_code: '130A',
    item_name: 'Item_name',
    item_type_name: 'Food',
    item_sub_type_name: 'Rice',
    company_name: 'Abc pvt ltd',
    delivered_quantity: 100,
    delivered_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    manufactured_date: null,
    expiry_date: null,
    total_quantity: 10,
    total_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    available_quantity: 10
  }, {
    item_code: '130A',
    item_name: 'Item_name',
    item_type_name: 'Food',
    item_sub_type_name: 'Rice',
    company_name: 'Abc pvt ltd',
    delivered_quantity: 100,
    delivered_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    manufactured_date: null,
    expiry_date: null,
    total_quantity: 5,
    total_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    available_quantity: 5
  },
  {
    item_code: '130A',
    item_name: 'Item_name',
    item_type_name: 'Food',
    item_sub_type_name: 'Rice',
    company_name: 'Abc pvt ltd',
    delivered_quantity: 100,
    delivered_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    manufactured_date: null,
    expiry_date: null,
    total_quantity: 5,
    total_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    available_quantity: 5
  },
  {
    item_code: '130A',
    item_name: 'Item_name',
    item_type_name: 'Food',
    item_sub_type_name: 'Rice',
    company_name: 'Abc pvt ltd',
    delivered_quantity: 100,
    delivered_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    manufactured_date: null,
    expiry_date: null,
    total_quantity: 10,
    total_measuring_unit: 'kg',
    available_quantity: 10
  }
];



a = a.map(i => JSON.stringify(i)) // convert objects to strings
  .filter((i, x, s) => s.indexOf(i) === x) // remove duplicate strings
  .map(i => JSON.parse(i)); // convert strings to objects

a = a.reduce((a, i, x, s) => {

  /**
   Object "a" new format:
   {
     item_code: {
        company_name: [ i ] // push the raw "i" item
     },
     item_code2: {
        company_name: []
     },
     ...
     item_codeN: {
        company_name: []
     }
   
   }
  */
  if (!a[i.item_code]) {
    a[i.item_code] = {};
  }
  if (!a[i.item_code][i.company_name]) {
    a[i.item_code][i.company_name] = [];
  }

  a[i.item_code][i.company_name].push(i);

  // Prepare the accumulator for the last Index of the loop
  if (x < s.length - 1) {
    return a;
  } else {

    // Get the accumulator keys (item_code's)
    let v = Object.keys(a);

    /** Mark the keys that we want to alter */
    // Arrays - These are the keys from your desired output that appear as arrays
    let stackKeys = ['delivered_quantity', 'manufactured_date', 'expiry_date', 'available_quantity'];
    // Numbers
    let sumKeys = ['total_quantity'];

    return v.reduce((acc, i, x) => {

      for (let item in a[i]) {

        const company = a[i][item].reduce((acc, i, x) => {

          for (const entry in i) {

            // Add the new keys in THIS accumulator
            if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(entry)) {
              acc[entry] = stackKeys.indexOf(entry) !== -1 ? [] : null;
            }

            // Apply Logic to Keys here
            // This should stack as a list
            if (stackKeys.indexOf(entry) !== -1) {
              acc[entry].push(i[entry]);

              // This will do a sum
            } else if (sumKeys.indexOf(entry) !== -1) {
              acc[entry] = acc[entry] + i[entry]

            } else {

              // Add the key "as is"
              acc[entry] = i[entry]

            }

          }

          return acc;

        }, {});

        acc.push(company);

      }

      return acc;

    }, []);

  }

}, {});

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Great. It works fine when my object has multiple item_codes.